# make specific tag visible only to logged in users in frontend

Tags: wordpress, tags, conditional-statements

In my wordpress cms, I display a regular list of all existing tags on my single template. Now I need to exclude one specific tag and show it only to the logged in people. What wordpress function/hook should I be looking into ?

EFFORTS - I know that I could use `is_user_logged_in()` and am also looking into [is_tag()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_tag) but how do I put this together. Currently I am having it displayed on my single template with [the_tags()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_tags) but it does not seem to offer such parameter to exclude a particular tag.

Psuedo code would be : `If user is logged in show all tags except this specific tag.`

Comment: can you post a little bit code?

Comment: You can hook a filter on **the_tags()**, the filter name is **get_the_tags**, one level deeper **get_the_terms**

Comment: Want you asked and what your pseudo code is saying doesn't match.

Comment: @AdrianPreuss I dont understand how my issue is relevant to cpt and roles ?   As evident only code that I have right now is `the_tags()` which displays a list of all the existing tags, I just need something to exclude one or two.

Comment: have removed that, to fast :D

Comment: wait 2 minutes, i check the filter live.

Comment: @PieterGoosen I have made some edits, hope it makes sense now.

Comment: i hope you can add the if-Statement? ^^

Comment: thanks and yes i can, just allow me a minute to try it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
add_filter('get_the_terms', 'tag_filter', 100, 1);

function tag_filter($tags) {
    $exclude = array('hello', 'demo', 'tag_one', 'tag_two');

    foreach($tags AS $index => $tag) {
        $name   = $tag->name;
        #$name  = $tag->slug;

        if(in_array(strtolower($name), $exclude)) {
            unset($tags[$index]);
        }
    }

    return $tags;
}
```

Comment: @Adrain Preuss Why does the 6th line about, the one greyed out ? How would your example look if i have two tags that are tag_one and tag_two ?

Comment: A sample, if you like to check the `name` or the `slug`, change it,.. ;)

Comment: Have changed the source. You only need to add/remove the entrys from `$exclude`

Comment: took a while to figure out how would I wrap it with if statement but it works.